# How to write a php code that will return an appropriate quote and populate <div id = "quote-section">?

Tags: javascript, php, json, wordpress

I have a quote.php file with the following code:

```
<div id="quote-section">
    <div id="quote"> 
        A famous man called <span id="quote_author">Confucious</span>, once said <span id="quote_txt">man who make mistake on elevator, wrong on many levels</span>
    </div>
    <input type="button" data-id="0" value="Quote 1">
    <input type="button" data-id="1" value="Quote 2">
    <input type="button" data-id="2" value="Quote 3">
    <input type="button" data-id="3" value="Quote 4">
</div>
```

Then the following file called cusomjavascript.js with the following code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    jQuery("#quote-section :button").click(function () {
        var data = {
            "quote": jQuery(this).data("id")
        };
        jQuery.post("/quote-service.php", data, function (response) {
            var decoded_response = JSON.parse(response);
            jQuery("#quote_txt").html(decoded_response.quote);
            jQuery("#quote_author").html(decoded_response.author);
        });
    });
});
```

The php that returns the values should be written in a file called, service-quote.php:

```
//use this as the number of the quote to return
$int_quote_no = filter_var($_POST['quote'], FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT); 

//here write the rest of the code that will return the quote:
```

Comment: Please clarify your question. What you exactly want?

Comment: **Hint**: Assuming your `quote.php` loads your JS, notice that you are calling `quote-service.php` here (not `service-quote.php`). You also need an Array of quotes in your Quote Service and then echo its `$int_quote_no` index with proper JSON headers (check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4064444/returning-json-from-a-php-script/25062961#25062961)). Anyway, judging by the comments in your code, it looks like you're trying to get your homework done here... Please, give it a try!

Comment: im a front end dev, trying to learn php, got this out of a php book, as a challenge, need help on it, don't know how and where to start. I want to know how do I approach this question?

Answer (score 0):

If you are a Frontend Dev who already knows Javascript, learning the basics of PHP should be easy...

I assume you understand what's going on in your HTML (`quote.php`) and JS (`customjavascript.js`). Basically, when you click one of the four buttons, JS launches an AJAX request (via [jQuery's `.post()`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/)) passing to your *Quote's Service* the ID of the expected quote.

In your service's file (`quote-service.php`) you already have a variable with the requested quote ID, called `$int_quote_no`.

Your client's code expects the quote to be a JS object with two keys:

1. `quote`
2. `author`

You can represent this object in your PHP as an [Array](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php), like this:

```
$quote_object = [
  'quote'  => 'Later equals never.',
  'author' => 'Uncle Bob'
];
```

In your case, you need four quote objects, so you could create a multidimensional array:

```
$quotes = [
  [
    'quote'  => 'Later equals never.',
    'author' => 'Uncle Bob'
  ],
  [
    'quote'  => 'Talk is cheap. Show me the code.',
    'author' => 'Linus Torvalds'
  ],
  // Add two more quotes...
];
```

Then you need to echo a JSON object to your client with the requested quote. It would be something like this (remember [the link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4064444/returning-json-from-a-php-script/25062961#25062961) I added to my previous comment regarding the JSON headers):

```
header('Content-type: application/json');
echo json_encode($quotes[ $int_quote_no ]);
```

Hope this helps. Btw, I'd recommend you to get started with PHP with some online resource on this topics. There are lots of them:

- http://php.net/manual/en/index.php
- https://www.codecademy.com/learn/php
- http://www.phptherightway.com/
- ...